# List only contains first two items

Tags: c#, list

Ok, I'm pretty sure isNumber is finally working. Thanks to everyone for the help. I think I'm almost ready to start working on this project for real. I'm just trying to wrap my head around lists.

What I'm doing is trying to check a bunch of inputs at once if they are numbers and store the results in a list. That way, to find out if one of them is a number, I can just check the corresponding value in the second list to find out.

So, my problem is that I'm clearly putting 3 things in my list, but when I have it print out the count of items it always displays 2. What the heck is wrong with this? Specifically, why does areNumbers always return a list of length 2 when I am obviously making it at least as long as numberOfNumbers?

PS I know my code doesn't look very nice yet. I want to get the basics right before I learn about style.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var maybe = new ArrayList(3);
        maybe.Add(100f);
        maybe.Add("not a number");
        maybe.Add(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(areNumbers(maybe).Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static ArrayList areNumbers(ArrayList maybeNumbers)
    {
        var theResults = new ArrayList(0);
        var numbersEnumerator = maybeNumbers.GetEnumerator();
        var numberOfNumbers = 0;

        try
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                numberOfNumbers = numberOfNumbers + 1;
                numbersEnumerator.MoveNext();
                var myIsNumber = isNumber(numbersEnumerator.Current);
                var myAreNumbers = new ArrayList(numberOfNumbers);
                myAreNumbers.Add(theResults);
                myAreNumbers.Add(myIsNumber);
                theResults = myAreNumbers;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return theResults;
        }
    }
    static bool isNumber(object theObject)
    {
        var s = theObject.GetType().ToString().ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return theObject is int || theObject is Int64 || theObject is float || theObject is double;
    }
```

Comment: What's the intention of this line? for (; ; ) {

Comment: Looks like the Catch grabs it when MoveNext fails. Weird, man.

Comment: You're adding three items to the list. Two of them can be interpreted as numbers, one cannot. You then print the count of the return value from `areNumbers`, and get 2. 2 of your values **are numbers**. Is this not what you intended?

Comment: It is one the worst codes that I've ever seen. First of all, instead of using `foreach` to iterate over `maybeNumbers`, you are using `GetEnumerator`, an infinite loop, and catching the `InvalidOperationException` thrown by 'MoveNext()`! You can replace all of this mess with a simple `foreach` loop.  Second, you are putting mixture of `bool`s and `ArrayList`s in a `ArrayList`. Why?

Comment: The guy is trying to learn and asks for advice. Encourage him.

Comment: There is no way the array will EVER have more (or less) than 2 items. You are re-creating the array and storing 2 items (a bool an the previous array) everytime you encounter a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop though a list of objects and give you a boolean response letting you know if they are numeric, which I think is what your code is doing in the end.

```
var testNumbers = new List<object>();
testNumbers.Add(15);
testNumbers.Add("AUUUGHH");
testNumbers.Add(42);

foreach (var i in testNumbers)
    Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(i));
```

Make sure you add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace in order to use IsNumeric()

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenters stated, the return value `areNumbers` will at most ever be an ArrayList with 2 items (first item would be an ArrayList of booleans for items 0 thru N-2; the second item would be a boolean value for the (N-1)th value).  If I stepped through the code in my head correctly, you would get an empty ArrayList if you sent it an empty ArrayList.

After one item:

```
areNumbers[0]: []       // empty ArrayList
areNumbers[1]: true
```

After two items:

```
areNumbers[0]: [[], true]  // after first item
areNumbers[1]: false
```

After three items

```
areNumbers[0]: [[[], true], false]  // after second item
areNumbers[1]: true
```

If you were to call with a 4th value that was numeric:

```
areNumbers[0]: [[[[], true], false], true]
areNumbers[1]: true
```

---

Now hopefully you aren't stuck in the pre-generics & pre-LINQ world...

`Where` will filter based on your `isNumber` function:

```
var maybeNumbers = new List<object>{ 100f, "not a number", 1000 };
var areNumbers = maybeNumbers.Where(isNumber).ToList();

Assert.AreEqual(2, areNumbers.Count());  //passes!
```

If you're pre-LINQ, try this:

```
List<object> maybeNumbers = new List<object>();
maybeNumbers.Add(100f);
maybeNumbers.Add("not a number");
maybeNumbers.Add(1000);

List<object> areNumbers = new List<object>();

foreach(object maybe in maybeNumbers)
{
    if (isNumber(maybe))
        areNumbers.Add(maybe);
}
```

Pre-generics (may not compile...)

```
ArrayList maybeNumbers = new ArrayList();
maybeNumbers.Add(100f);
maybeNumbers.Add("not a number");
maybeNumbers.Add(1000);

ArrayList areNumbers = new ArrayList();

foreach(object maybe in maybeNumbers)
{
    if (isNumber(maybe))
        areNumbers.Add(maybe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- get rid of endless loop
- iterate through your maybe numbers
- surround with try ... catch only isNumber

If have exception do not increase number of numbers.
And do not return generics for this because what you really need to return is an integer only.

You need sth like (pseudo code):

```
numberOfNumbers = 0;

while ( there is sth to handle )
{
   take element to handle
   try
   {
      check it
      numberOfNumbers++;
   }
   catch ( )
   {
     // not a number
   }
   go to the next element
}

return numberOfNumbers
```

Assuming of course that isNumber throws some execption when your maybe number is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

1.don't rely on try/catch for normal code flow. try/catch is for catching exceptional situations

2.why do you need to build a isNumber method? double.tryParse or Convert.ToDouble() will do similar things (google up to find the difference)

3.No ideea what myAreNumbers is supposed to do but you are basically adding a bool and a list to a new list on every iteration

```
static ArrayList areNumbers(ArrayList maybeNumbers) 
{  
    var theResults = new ArrayList(0);
    foreach(var possibleNumber in maybeNumbers) 
    {
        double myDouble;
        if (double.tryParse(possibleNumber, out myDouble))
                   theResults.Add(possibleNumber);// OR theResults.Add(myDouble); //depending on what you want
    }
    return theResults; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var maybe = new ArrayList(3);
    maybe.Add(100f);
    maybe.Add("not a number");
    maybe.Add(1000);
    foreach (var item in maybe)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    ArrayList res = new ArrayList(maybe.ToArray().Where((o) => o.IsNumber()).ToArray());
    foreach (var item in res)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static bool IsNumber(this object item)
{
    const TypeCode filter = TypeCode.Double | TypeCode.Int16 | TypeCode.Int32 | TypeCode.Int64
        | TypeCode.Single | TypeCode.UInt16 | TypeCode.UInt32 | TypeCode.UInt64;
    Type t = item.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive)
    {                
        TypeCode code = System.Type.GetTypeCode(t);
        return (code & filter) > 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```